# How do I give reference to functions from one class to another?

Tags: php, class, reference, external

The following is my simplified code

```
<?php
  $database = new db();
  $file = new file();
  $input = new input();
  $output = new output();

  $data = "SELECT * FROM table;";
  $input->page($data);

  class db {
        public function queryExecute($var) {
              $var = $this->queryEncode($var);
              $var = $this->querySubmit($var);
        return $var;
        }

        public function queryEncode($var) {
              // Do somthing
        return $var;
        }

        public function querySubmit($var) {
              // Do somthing
        return $var;
        }
  }
```

The issue is when I add this to the code:

```
  class input {
        public function page($data) {
              // Do something
              $pageQuery = db::queryExecute($data);
        }
  }
```

With this, there are two things I have to do. First, I have to hide the errors for the `db::queryExecute($data);` code if the server is set to strict. And now for the second problem. I can't seem to use this line of code (which is the only way I have yet found possible for referencing other classes besides using Abstract) if the class that is being referenced is referencing yet another class but this time within it's own class.

For better explanation, the procedure is as follows:

1. Grab the `$data` variable and send it to the `$input->page()` function ( `$input->page($data)` ).
2. Referencing the `db` class, the `$input->page()` function sends the information onto the  `$database->queryExecute()` function by means of the `db::queryExecute()` format (  `db::queryExecute($data)` ).
3. But because we are using the `::`, when `$database->queryExecute()` references `$database->queryEncode()` and `$database->querySubmit()` using `$this->` operator ( `$this->queryEncode()` and `$this->querySubmit()` ), `$this->` currently belongs to `$input->` and not `$database->`.

So what's the solution... Reference the other class differently (instead of `::`)? Use a `$_GLOBAL` variable when I define my classes? Use something other than `$this->`? Configure all of the classes to use `ABSTRACT`/`EXTENDS` (or `INTERFACE`)?

The following error outputted refers to `$var = $this->queryEncode($var);`:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method input::querySubmit() in C:\[...]\global.php on line 12`

Comment: Post the errors you are receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not make static call to not static function. Pass `$db instance` to page, or provide global access to the database (via global registry, singleton or other method). But best, pass the dependency - the database instance, to the method.

```
<?php
  $database = new db();
  $file = new file();
  $input = new input($database);
  $output = new output();

  $data = "SELECT * FROM table;";
  $input->page($data);

  class db {
        public function queryExecute($var) {
              $var = $this->queryEncode($var);
              $var = $this->querySubmit($var);
        return $var;
        }

        public function queryEncode($var) {
              // Do somthing
        return $var;
        }

        public function querySubmit($var) {
              // Do somthing
        return $var;
        }
  }

  class input {
    protected $_database;
    public function __construct($database) {
        $this->_database = $database;
    }
    public function page($data) {
          // Do something
          $pageQuery = $this->_database->queryExecute($data);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you please give me brief an example of and/or better explain what you mean by passing the dependency to the method if that's not asking for too much?

Comment: $input->page($data, $database); // you can also pass the database in the page's constructor.

Comment: I have tried this but to no avail. I copy lines 3-5 from the code given above into the beginning of the `db` class such as `private $file = new file();` but then it gives me this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_NEW in C:\[...]\global.php on line 11`

Comment: you cannot instantiate objects in the member declaration. You have to use the class constructor for this. Added an example.

Comment: Ah, that may fix it! I figured though that you did not have to use the `__construct()` class to initially set variables (or classes in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You can only use the double-colon operator on static, constant, or overridden properties or methods of a class. See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) on this. Use `->` instead.

Comment: That was my original intent, but I could not get `->` to work since the variable was not visible to the class.